# Maven release plugin configuration and example

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-plugin

I'm learning to get automatic versioning updates on the filename of the JAR file for my Java project, I'm currently using IntelliJ. I'm following [this guideline](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/usage.html), I've already added this plugin in the Pom file, but in the article, it says I need to set a different username for SCM, and also need to set where to tag the files in Subversion. I'm new to Maven, not sure if I fully understand the instruction, are those steps compulsive or it denpends? Should those commands execute in Command Prompt?

```
mvn -Dusername=your_scm_username release:prepare
```

and how to set the repository (how to specify the URL for , is it a local URL?)

```
<configuration>
          <tagBase>https://svn.mycompany.com/repos/myapplication/releases</tagBase>
        </configuration>
```

Is there an example regarding how to set up and use this plugin, and also how to relate it to Jenkins? I found some articles online but they are so old, some of them were written from 8 or 9 years ago. Would be great if someone can throw a link with example and explain to me, many thanks.

Comment: Are those old articles actually outdated though? According to the archive site (http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/release/) the current release (2.5.3) is dated 2015-10-17  - which is 4 years old. The oldest version (2.2.2) is dated 2012-12-29. Overall, I'd wager those old articles are still mostly accurate.

Comment: "automatic versioning updates" : Please clarify "automatic" here as there are several levels of automation you might be aiming for (especially as you've mentioned Jenkins too).

Comment: @JasonWarner The archive is not really relevant take a look on the current pages https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/ which is correct and yes theey are still valid. The most important things is to correctly configure the developerConnection correctly (https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/usage.html) and if you use default layout in SVN (trunk/tag/branches) you don't need to setup location for tagging. Please show your pom file. Related to Jenkins the question is: Should Jenkins do the work or Maven?

Comment: @drekbour By automatic I mean updates versioning automate after every push to master by following the semantic versioning naming rule.

Comment: @khmarbaise I think you missed my point. I was using the archive to demonstrate that just because a tutorial is old doesn't always make it worthless. There have only been 3 minor versions released in the last 7 years. Any article he found should still be usable.